# How to print int in print?

Tags: python, python-3.x

print the price of the car in the print statement ,when executed gives error as

> only strings can be concatenated in print stement

```
class Board:
    def __init__(x1,car,price):
        x1.car=car
        x1.price=price
    def init1(x1):
        print("They brought a car "+x1.car +"for rupees" x1.price) ### this is where I need the print of price .
    y=Board("xylo",2000)
y.init1()
```

They bought a car xylo for rupees 2000 -> expected out put.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 3.6+, you can use `f-string`.

```py
print(f"They brought a car {x1.car} for rupees {x1.price}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply pass your strings and integers as separate arguments to `print`, if you don't need further formatting:

```
print("They brought a car", x1.car, "for rupees", x1.price)
```

The integers will be converted to strings as needed, and the different arguments will be printed separated by a space by default - you could change this using the `sep=` keyword argument of print.

Answer (score 0):

As the message tells, you can concatenate only strings to another string, because the value you are concatenating needs to be of the *same* type.

Better approach:

```
 print("They brought a car {} for rupees {}".format(x1.car, x1.price))
```

Answer (score 0):

use morden string formatting.

```py
"They bought a car {} for rupees {}".format("xylo", 2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The print function can take multiple arguments. By default they are separated with a space (you can override this behavior with the `sep` keyword argument).

```
print("They brought a car", x1.car, "for rupees", x1.price)
```

Answer (score 0):

The price has type int, so you first need to convert the int to str

```
print("They brought a car "+ x1.car + "for rupees" + str(x1.price))
```

If you have Python >= 3.6 using f-strings would be nicer (note the 'f' in front of the string)

```
print(f"They brought a car {x1.car} for rupees {x1.price})
```